# how to use asp.net list view control of framework 3.5 into framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I use the list view control of framework 3.5 in a framework 2.0 app?  If so, how?

Comment: could you please revise your question?

Comment: i want to use control listview in asp.net 3.5 now my framework in change so i want to use that control in asp.net 2.0 framework so is there possible??

Answer (score 2):

The ListView control was introduced in .NET 3.5. It cannot be used with .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DataList....

http://forums.asp.net/p/1193228/2057339.aspx#2057339